# Custom Floating Buttons in Titanium

Tags: appcelerator, titanium-mobile

My app design has two round buttons sitting on top of a map view. I want to achieve this with Titanium / Alloy (pure Titanium is fine too) but nothing has come up in the docs. How can I create floating buttons? E.g. **how can I create buttons that sit on top of another view?**

On that same note I wanted to add custom behavior when I tap the button. I wanted four more buttons to fan out from the top button across the view making a slight arc and dim the screen.

Comment: just use zIndex ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

- zIndex
- add the view at the end of your XML

An example of a Floating Action button with a custom menu is available at https://github.com/k0sukey/be.k0suke.tifab

Place the menu items at the same position as the collapsed button. When you click the button you show them and move them to the desired position (`Ti.UI.createAnimation()`). To fade out the background you create a fullscreen view with `backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.5"` which is invisible at first and when you click the menu button you fade it in or just set it to visible.

Comment: yes this is exactly the resource I'm looking for! Nailed it! I can take it from here. :)